# How to auto read file without input, while ability to input when necessary. PYTHON

Tags: python

```
while 1:
 f = open('list.txt', mode='r')
 print(f.read())
 f.close()
 f = open('list.txt', mode='a')
 with open("list.txt",'a',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   x = input('message: ')
   f.write(f'| {name}: {x}\n')
 f.close()
```

I need to be able to print(f.read()) every second, while still being able to get the value of x whenever. How?

Comment: in line 5 you open the file `f = open(...)` and then in line 6 you are opening an already opened file `with open(...)`

Comment: Perhaps you need two different threads?